# How to check if an appropriate enumerable is a palindrome

Tags: ruby, palindrome, enumerable

Obviously, a hash would not work for this kind of test. Anyways, here's what I have so far:

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    arr = []
    self.reverse_each do |x|
      arr << x
    end
    self == arr
  end
end
```

Another idea I had was to cycle through arr and self element by element with a for loop to check.

Comment: Is this a homework question by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    a = to_a
    a == a.reverse
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'Tiger'
p "#{x} is planidrome" if x ==  x.reverse #=> no ouput
x = 'RADAR'
p "#{x} is planidrome" if x ==  x.reverse #=> "RADAR is planidrome"

module Enumerable
  def palindrome?
    p  self.to_a ==  self.to_a.reverse
  end
end
['r','a','d','a','r'].palindrome? #=> true
```

Comment: This is for Strings, not Enumerables.